# how to use git and sbt to add library to sbt project

Tags: git, web-services, scala, sbt

I'm a newbie in scala, sbt and git.
How to use git command line to download the two libraries, reboot and sjson?
How to use sbt to either create jar files that I can put to lib folder of my project, or use them as a dependency in sbt?
Usage is similar to and idea gotten from: http://aloiscochard.blogspot.fi/2011/05/simple-rest-web-service-client-in-scala.html

http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html

```
echo 'libraryDependencies += "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.0"' > build.sbt
sbt console
```

did not do the trick for me. I guess I need at least some version of git and sbt for this to work?

The libraries:
https://github.com/dispatch/reboot
https://github.com/debasishg/sjson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Git to use these two particular libraries, but yes you do need to have SBT installed in order to use SBT. You can download SBT from here:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html

To add the libraries as dependencies to an SBT project, create a `build.sbt` file in the root folder of your project (you can name it anything as long as it ends in `.sbt`), and put the following content in it:

```
name := "test"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "net.debasishg" %% "sjson" % "0.19",
    "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.0"
)
```

(The `name` setting isn't strictly necessary. And you can of course use another name than "test".)

The sjson library is a bit odd in that it doesn't list its published `groupId` and `artifactId` in the documentation (at least I couldn't find it), and as such it seemed that you would have to download the source it and build it yourself, but it is actually published at the address given above.

You can run SBT (`sbt` in your console) and execute the `update` command to check that the libraries are downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Kunt's instructions and it cannot work. Here are the error messages:

[error] {file:/home/deryk/Documents/Eclipse/workspace/SBT/first/}default-eeadde/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: net.debasishg#sjson_2.9.1;0.19: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: net.databinder.dispatch#dispatch-core_2.9.1;0.11.0: not found